# fullpage.js navigate back by url hash not work in mobile

Tags: fullpage.js

```
<body>
<div data-anchor="page_1"></div>
<div data-anchor="page_2"></div>
<div data-anchor="page_3"></div>
<div data-anchor="page_4"></div>
</body>
```

1. When I open my home page `http://my.site/index`, the default page is
   `page_1` and there is no hash part `#page_1` in URL.
2. I slid down the screen and current page changes to `page_2` with URL
   `http://my.site/index#page_2`
3. I navigate back and the URL changes to
   `http://my.site/index`. The page is still on `page_2` which I wanted
   is `page_1`.

Are there some options on creating `fullpage.js` or should I set the default URL to `http://my.site/index#page_1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that's a well known bug in fullPage.js for which there's no solution so far.

You can read more about it on the repo's github issues forum:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/950

To prevent this, you can force fullpage.js to ignore the anchors by using the options `recordHistory: false` or `lockAnchors: true`.